# Php Recursively entering categories to MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, recursion, yii

I want to enter the following data structure (ignoring category_id, parent_id, position, and level) into mongo Db according to their model tree structures method with child references: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

```
    object(Node)#1 (6) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["parent_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "Root"
  ["position"]=>
  int(0)
  ["level"]=>
  int(0)
  ["children"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Node)#2 (6) {
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["parent_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Root MySite.com"
      ["position"]=>
      int(0)
      ["level"]=>
      int(1)
      ["children"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(Node)#3 (6) {
          ["category_id"]=>
          int(15)
          ["parent_id"]=>
          int(2)
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Widgets"
          ["position"]=>
          int(68)
          ["level"]=>
          int(2)
          ["children"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            object(Node)#4 (6) {
              ["category_id"]=>
              int(24)
              ["parent_id"]=>
              int(15)
              ["name"]=>
              string(11) "Blue Widget"
              ["position"]=>
              int(68)
              ["level"]=>
              int(3)
              ["children"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
            }
            [1]=>
            object(Node)#5 (6) {
              ["category_id"]=>
              int(25)
              ["parent_id"]=>
              int(15)
              ["name"]=>
              string(13) "Purple Widget"
              ["position"]=>
              int(68)
              ["level"]=>
              int(3)
              ["children"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Node)#6 (6) {
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(100)
      ["parent_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "FooBar.com"
      ["position"]=>
      int(0)
      ["level"]=>
      int(1)
      ["children"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(Node)#7 (6) {
          ["category_id"]=>
          int(150)
          ["parent_id"]=>
          int(100)
          ["name"]=>
          string(6) "Gizmos"
          ["position"]=>
          int(68)
          ["level"]=>
          int(2)
          ["children"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            object(Node)#8 (6) {
              ["category_id"]=>
              int(240)
              ["parent_id"]=>
              int(150)
              ["name"]=>
              string(11) "Blue Gizmos"
              ["position"]=>
              int(68)
              ["level"]=>
              int(3)
              ["children"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
            }
            [1]=>
            object(Node)#9 (6) {
              ["category_id"]=>
              int(250)
              ["parent_id"]=>
              int(150)
              ["name"]=>
              string(13) "Purple Gizmos"
              ["position"]=>
              int(68)
              ["level"]=>
              int(3)
              ["children"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't quite come up with the right php code to traverse the tree and insert the data.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 public function behaviors()
  {
    return array(
        'embeddedArrays' => array(
          'class'=>'ext.YiiMongoDbSuite.extra.EEmbeddedArraysBehavior',
          'arrayPropertyName' => 'categories',
          'arrayDocClassName' => 'Category',
          ));
  }

  public function setCategories($user_id)
  {
    $api = new ApiCategory($user_id); 
    $cats = $api->getCategories(); // retrieves structure above

    $this->recursiveCategoryTree($cats);

    $this->save(); // save the entire array of embedded documents

    if($this->getErrors())
      var_dump($this->getErrors);

  }

  public function recursiveCategoryTree($tree, $i = 0)
  {
    foreach ($tree->children as $child) {
      if ($count($child->children ) > 0 ){
        $this->categories[$i] = new Category();
        $this->categories[$i]->_id = $tree->name; 
        $i++;
        $this->getCategoryTree($child, $i);
      }
      else{
        $this->categories[--$i]->children[] = $child->name;
      } 
    } 
  }
```

I've tried several different ways to get it to work, but I'm not sure how the counter should work exactly, or maybe I'm way off base? The php framework I'm using (http://canni.github.com/YiiMongoDbSuite/xhtml/basic.arrays.embedded-documents.html) makes you use the categories[index] method. According to the documentation it should work like this:

```
$data = new Data();
$data->categories[0] = new Category();
$data->categories[0]->_id = 'Root';
$data->categories[0]->children = array("Root MySite.com", "FooBar.com");
$data->categories[1]->_id = 'Root MySite.com';
$data->categories[1]->children = {immediate children};
$data->save();
```

Any help with this method would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:
With all the new data, i clearly understand what you are trying to achieve.**

So i edited out my old function, this is a new one that should work strait in your code.
Let me know so i can adjust if needed.

```
public function setCategories($user_id)
{
    $api = new ApiCategory($user_id);
    $cats = $api->getCategories(); // retrieves structure above

    $newCats = null;
    self::recursiveCatTree($newCats, $cats);
    $this->categories = $newCats;

    $this->save(); // save the entire array of embedded documents

    if($this->getErrors())
        var_dump($this->getErrors);

}

public static function recursiveCatTree(&$result, $parent)
{
    $children = $parent['children'];

    //we unset the children so we dont have manually set every other variable
    unset( $parent['children']);
    $result = new Category();
    $result->attributes = $parent;

    //then loop the children, if no children it wont loop
    // so it will just be an empty    array
    foreach($children as $child)
    {
       $baby = null;
       self::recursiveCatTree($baby, $child);
       $result->children[] = $baby;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks DarkMukke, I added some more of the model and an example of what I'm looking for. I hope that makes sense. I'm trying to traverse the category tree, and SAVE it as an array of embedded documents.

Comment: $newCats isn't returning correctly.. the children are getting inserted as Category objects, it should really just be an array of names: eg: $data->categories[0]->children = array((string)"Root MySite.com", (string)"FooBar.com");

Comment: you have all the data already in your array, why lopp it again and make them objects of a class ? i thought you wanted to store the above  data in mongo